# "Eigenvalue" of gradient

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R)$. I want to show that there is $x\in\mathbb R^n$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ with $\nabla f(x) = \lambda x$, but I have no idea how to do this. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Use Lagrangian multiplier: look for the max/min of $f$ when restricted to a sphere.

Comment: An *eigenvalue* of the gradient operator would be a $\lambda$ such that $\nabla f = \lambda f$, so this isn't quite that.

Comment: By John's argument, we should be able to do this for any $\lambda$ by repeating the argument for 
$$
\tilde f(x) = f(x) - c\|x\|^2
$$
for the appropriate $c \in \Bbb R$.